# Чем ловить Undefined Behaviour?

Tags: c++, c, неопределённое-поведение

После прочтения [статьи на Хабре](https://habr.com/ru/post/592233/) стало понятно, что Undefined Behaviour далеко не всегда очевиден. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какие существуют инструменты для наиболее полного выявления UB для разных ОС?

На Linux мне известны [Valgrind](https://valgrind.org/) (ловит не всё, так как работает уже с результатом компиляции) и санитайзеры, но даже последние выявляют не все случаи неопределённого поведения.

Comment: Отладкой... Если вы не будете отлаживать ваш код, то никакая утилита вам не поможет, если не хотите этого делать, то берите другой язык в котором нет UB. За скорость нужно платить, не хотите платить, используйте медленные языки, пример c#. Так же пишите тесты для вашего кода, упростит вам жизнь.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что какой-то инструмент в состоянии отлавливать такие неприятности. Например, как отловить сдвиг на слишком большую ширину, если она вычисляется во время работы?...

Comment: @Kotomi, отладка - само собой разумеющееся, но проблема в том, что при одних параметрах компиляции может возникнуть странная ситуация, а при других нет. Или с одним компилятором она может возникать, а с другим нет. Или, наконец, может произойти, как в статье - разработчики компилятора в очередной раз решат где-то добавить оптимизацию, из-за чего часть программ, не соответствующих стандарту, станет работать не так, как предполагалось. Вопрос здесь больше в том, как ловить нарушения стандарта.

Comment: @Harry, санитайзеры такое точно ловят. Мне кажется, что тут нужен комплексный подход, включающий в себя использование как санитайзеров, так и инструментов для статического анализа

Comment: Его нельзя ловить, его можно только не допускать. Отладка или valgrind ловят последствия некорректного поведения программы, а не неопределенное поведение. Чтобы снизить риск закрадывания UB следует компилировать с включенными предупреждениями и использовать статические анализаторы кода.

Comment: Сомневаюсь. Особенно если у меня такое происходит раз на 100 запусков, например. Да и что — они каждую операцию процессора прощупывают? Одно дело отлавливать операции с памятью, и совсем другое — мелкие битовые операции, например.

Comment: @SunnyCove, эм... Очень просто: [`-pedantic-errors`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) : `Give an error whenever the base standard (see -Wpedantic) requires a diagnostic, in some cases where there is undefined behavior at compile-time and in some other cases that do not prevent compilation of programs that are valid according to the standard. This is not equivalent to -Werror=pedantic, since there are errors enabled by this option and not enabled by the latter and vice versa. `

Comment: @user7860670, да, действительно, с Valgrind я погорячился

Comment: Если хочется код без UB, то стоит писать на Ada/Spark

Comment: @user7860670, спасибо! Не будет ли слишком большой нескромностью попросить написать развёрнутый ответ с известными Вам инструментами для диагностики кода на C/C++, их достоинствами и недостатками?

Comment: Чуток уменьшить UB может переход на Rust

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Теория Computer Science прямо говорит, что только глядя на код не всегда возможно установить, есть в нем UB или нет - потому что это сводится к так называемой *проблеме останова*.

Следовательно, остаются три способа:

- формально доказывать для каждого кусочка кода, что он не приводит к UB. Такое формальное доказательство не противоречит вышесказонному, поскольку, постольку при доказательстве используется больше информации, чем содержится в исходном тексте программы. Например, используются знания предметной области, в которой работает код. *Если формальное доказательство проведено без ошибок, то и UB в коде нет.*
- обычно, ошибки приводящие к UB выглядят довольно типично. Статические анализаторы кода хорошо натренированы на поиск таких паттернов, поэтому позволяют выловить какую-то долю UB
- насыщать код большим количеством проверок корректности данных для того, чтобы выявить проблему на раннем этапе отладки и тестирования (и как можно раньше по ходу выполнения программы). В сочетании с [fuzzy-тестированием](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3) (когда в программу подают всякую бредятину, в том числе, и сгенерированную случайно) это также позволяет выловить не только UB, но и банальные ошибки в алгоритмах.

На практике, работает комбинация методов - в процессе написания кода следует держать в голове ситуации "что может пойти не так" и не допускать их, при тестах подавать не только хорошие данные, но и явную подставу, а при помещении в репозитарий скармливать код в [Coverity](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coverity)/[PVS Studio](https://pvs-studio.com/ru/pvs-studio/download/)/[Clang](https://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), и собирать с самыми жесткими диагностиками.

Дополнительными способами улучшайзинга могут быть:

- отказ от глобальных переменных
- использование как можно большего количества иммутабельных сущностей, повсеместная расстановка `const` в частности
- Соблюдение `RAII`, применение только умных указателей
- Список можно дополнять очень многими пунктами, все зависит, в конечном итоге, от бюджета ресурсов на разработку.